# Update multiple entries in single query. Android SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I store around 30 items in database, they have own ID and POSITION. Quite frequently I need to  update their positions. Doing it in loop is not a good idea due performance issues. So I'm thinking if is there a way to just pass list of ID's and list of POSITION's associated with ID in single query?

Answer (score 0):

You can update a single query just add this code to you sqlite code.

```
 public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   // values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
  //  values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());
  //        values.put(KEY_ID1, contact.getID1());
  //  values.put(KEY_FLAG, contact.getFlag());
    values.put(KEY_FLAG_PLUS, contact.getFlagPlus());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}
```

and in the activity where you have to update the sqlite by this syntax

```
db.update(new Contact("",""));
```

Comment: That will update just one row, but I need something like

public void updateList(List<Integer, Integer> list) {
// do the job
}